# How to create secure SOAP body using .net webservices wse or wcf?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, soap

Currently I am consuming Java web services to .NEt. Here I am using WSE 3.0 for consuming Java secure web services. But I got the error:

> "Exception thrown: Referenced security token could not be retrieved"

After I compare java SOAP Request and .NET SOAP Request.here I found I am sending correct .net SOAP header but body I am sending wrong. Can any one help me on how to send secure body request form .net Client

Below, I given Java and .Net SOAP XML Data:

**.Net Request XML SOAP Body (present I am Sending)**

```
<soap:Body wsu:Id="Id-165fc268-5917-43b9-aed2-091fb948c508">
          <xenc:EncryptedData Id="Enc-20dbd181-a655-4843-882a-b8b36b9d028d" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
            <xenc:CipherData>
              <xenc:CipherValue>UO32nmFhQZ4JBNuWk6xTz20FpjfPWQqr1F5zqOf7uQ6hBJzfndGAJvb/l/MgT0x7P2ZTiEeNj51ZDYKDZrQ1Ax3SCJyzacX6suemUVWmMaVGtJ8DJPqka7T3xDkWpgVlDmc1am1B+E7SXdfd9RIINv+JpYhF5Fx4m3ZaeYvPQLVrvF3Rpvya2L1mC/LeHVYwM/ep6x5f9tQnz50UASBHIA==</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
          </xenc:EncryptedData>
        </soap:Body>
```

**JAVA Requested XML SOAP Body (Expected from java web server )**

```
      <soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2">
<xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="ED-5" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">

<wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
<wsse:Reference URI="#EK-7FBF3DBE856BC8B2BC14527661038314"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>SQ0nnx45EPDL5uoFRzeTjJy6+FhaCZTK/3LRz5DrPM4qAQ2JzARNiLmuj61YSHd6nOMVy1QmPCqH5gG6PIIN8x47r10fzOkuisxpcOaUdnFL3bY55AvfyL6fUbSfcp+fl3qw6SAB3QF0AR1thqpfKBttBv8b7GxbpApCZg6TWaw8nD7G7dVmtdpDBJN7uQSQJu5ibdBGLzbVoF9YtliYH1mbdswL4KVJtZKUl2UAQqDtbxgXAkKtNwNyq4pt7N+HVhX00mZMxiTE0IyRyfgQhwp6afsTvsGVmdKxcpWtRoOFmmIHhrTeXJal/jJAI84mmg5EV44TJezFFbEyqsL+vhhR/N6oITaa
</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
</soap:Body>
```

Any idea on how I can send the same request as the Java to a server from .Net web service or WCF  ?

Comment: Do you have a X.509 certificate? Usually it comes as a pfx file?

Comment: yes i am using x.509 certificate in my code

Comment: We want to see your client side code. Looks like it cannot find the cert or you are using a wrong cert.

Comment: hi ,kosala w thanks for reply  i am using correct certificate i.e clientinvoke.pfx i am get correct responce form server but with some error "referece token was missed" ..so i just check the entire sopa responce from server in input trace file i found i missing in <body > <KeyInfo ><SecurityTokenReference ></body> any idea how can i pass those both tags in side body element....?

Comment: As I said, we need to see your client side call. You may not have included the cert in your web service call at all.

Comment: hi kosala w i am unable to provide code here please give your mail id i will give the code ..actually i am using the policy file for passing certificates like see the reference code https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529356.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this to integrate X.509 to your web service client.

```
       public void MyWebServiceClient()
       {
            using (var client = new MyWebService())
            {
                try
                {
                    //calls the web service
                    client.Url = //Your server EndpointUri;

                    //assign cert
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;
                    string certificatePath = //certificate path
                    string certificatePassword = //certificate password
                    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
                    client.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

                    //var result = client.WebServiceCall(your input);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }


    public bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {            
        // accept all certificates
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: hi kosala w thanks for advise i am using here windows forms application my code like bellow